# Angular 9: Http POST comes empty

Tags: angular

I am not getting response from my backend and dont know what to do.

This is my request:

```
   httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        // Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
      })
    };

getServiceById(request: string): Observable < any > {
      const url = this.endpoint + '/GetById';
      return this.http.post<Service>(url, request, this.httpOptions).pipe(
          retry(3),
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

Used on component like this:

```
  getServiceById(id: string) {
    this.httpService.getServiceById(id).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.service = resp;
      console.log('getServiceById: ', this.service);
    });
  }
```

The request works

[image]

The parameters are well

[image]

But the response comes empty

[image]

This is not a backend problem, i already tested and work well. Maybe im doing something bad on angular's request.

Comment: In the attached screenshot I can see that you get HTTP 202 response. I don't know how does API look like, but maybe you don't get expected response because processing has not finished yet.

Comment: 202 is expected. The endpoint return a Accepted HTTP and the object in the response. I tested the back with postman and swagger, and works well.

Comment: I've heard some responses to POST requests come empty when Windows is not activated :p
More seriously, as Vojtone comment suggests there seem to be an issue with the processing of the requests, when they come from the angular client. As that service is running locally, judging by the screenshot, it's worth inspecting logs or setting breakpoints there.